# CodeIgniter flashdata incoerence

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

So, I've been struggling with this for some time, but to no avail. My research didn't help much, either. Here it is: I built a test to prevent people to go to the alter page of an module by typing the address directly in the url without the id of the registry to be altered (therefore causing trouble in the DB). Simply put, it searches for the id passed as parameter in the url in the DB; if it has a match, it proceeds, if not, I redirect to the main module page with an error message passed via flashdata. I use a similar process to impede the insertion/alteration of registries if a field from a different table is not defined (as it is required in both in order to work, as the tables are related). A rough example of what I'm doing in the Controller is:

```
if(is_numeric($id)) $search=$this->model_foo->search($id);
else
{
  $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message','not numeric');
  redirect('myurl/index','refresh');
}
if($search->num_rows()==0)
{
  $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message','not found');
  redirect('myurl/index','refresh');
}
$search=$this->model_foo2->list();
if ($search->num_rows()==0)
{
  $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message','other table empty');
  redirect('myurl/index','refresh');
}
```

And my view (index) is like this:

```
<?php
 $error=$this->session->flashdata('error_message');
 $success=$this->session->flashdata('success_message'); /*success_message goes after a successful inset/update*/
 if ($error!="")echo $error;
?>
```

So here is the issue: the success messages show up normally (I checked and double checked, they are being declared in the Controller the exact same way the error ones), as well as the 'not numeric' one, but not the 'not found' and 'other table empty' ones. I'm really confused by this one, since the flashdata seems to work in some instances and not in others, which is specially weird given the flashdata are being declared in pretty much the same way... =/ Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, this is my first post here, so (try to) be patient ;D Thanks in advance for any help in this matter.

EDIT: Found out the source of the issue. It was something with my browsers cache storage. Rebooted my machine and cleaned the cache and the output worked like a charm. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: have you checked if the flashdata it actually being set? try to put a print $this->session->all_userdata();exit; after $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message','not found'); and check if the values there...

Comment: actually i dont think print $this->session->all_userdata();exit; will work, may $this->session->flashdata('error_message');exit;...i just want to be sure the value is set before it goes to redirect.

Comment: You might want to try not using the 'refresh' option in your redirect - that might be interfering with the flash data.

Comment: @pecci, I did run some tests on that matter. The 'not found' flashdata is indeed not being set, but the 'not numeric' is, witch again is most awkward since I'm setting them up pretty much the same way...I'm almost sure that I'm setting the 'not found' with the right syntax, but still it's not setting up. any ideas?

Comment: @SamDufel, I run refresh with flashdata in almost all the modules of the system, none of them has ever showed signs of trouble. Also, the messages that worked also were setted before a 'refreshed' redirect

Comment: One other thing - the default implementation of CI sessions stores the data in cookies.  If you start approaching the size limit for cookies, you'll start seeing dropped data in your sessions.

Answer (score 0):

So, i just improved your code a little bit so you can try and debug...

Controller:

```
$arr = array('error_message' => '');
if(!empty($id) && is_numeric($id)) {
  $search=$this->model_foo->search($id);

  if($search->num_rows()==0) {
    $arr['error_message'] = 'not found';
  } else {
    $search=$this->model_foo2->list();
    if ($search->num_rows()==0) {
      $arr['error_message'] = 'other table empty';
    }
  }
} else {
  $arr['error_message'] = 'not numeric';
}

$this->session->set_flashdata($arr);
redirect('myurl/index');
```

View (same):

```
<?php
 $error=$this->session->flashdata('error_message');
 $success=$this->session->flashdata('success_message'); /*success_message goes after a successful inset/update*/
 if ($error!="")echo $error;
?>
```

Give a try with this and before check if the message appears, make sure the flashdata is set.

Comment: Tried that out, still get the same results. Also ran tests and the times the messages aren't shown is because of flashdata not being set

Comment: @luck_ponte, i did another change in the code, i use like this in my projects, give it a try...this way works for me...

Comment: weird, still got the issue...again, checked if the flashdata was set, it didn't happen for the 'not found'...